# SetProgressBarIndeterminateVisibility lack of understanding

Tags: android

If I request a progress dialog like this in my main Activity then it is displayed as expected:

```
          requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_INDETERMINATE_PROGRESS);  
  setProgressBarIndeterminateVisibility(true);
```

But if I set the visibility to "false", and then reset it to "true" inside the called procedure in which I want to deploy it, nothing is displayed. Moving the requestWindowFeature to the procedure causes an exception. How should I be doing this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to call `requestWindowFeature()` only once, in `onCreate()`, before you call `setContentView()`. Then you can use `setProgressBarIndeterminateVisibility(true|false)` to show or hide the progress indicator from anywhere in the activity (as long as it is on the UI thread, of course).

Comment: I haven't declared another thread, a proc A is called from the activity onCreate proc and the proc B which is attempting to use the progress indicator is called "onClick" from proc A. Should this work?

Comment: As long as you don't try to call `requestWindowFeature()` twice, yes.

Comment: Using it so?: `    setProgressBarIndeterminateVisibility(true);
  try {
    spage = CustomHttpClient.myHttpGet(sURL);
   } catch (Exception e) {
    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "failed to GET webpage", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    e.printStackTrace();
   }
  setProgressBarIndeterminateVisibility(false);`

Comment: That's the general idea, yes.However, your HTTP call will block the UI thread, so you might not see the progress indicator. It's best used with combination with a background thread or `AsyncTask`.

Comment: Ah, that makes sense, the HTTP is blocking of course. Thanks!